# Подгрузка данных и исключение во время нажатия на ListBox

Tags: wpf, .net, c#

Есть listBox1  и listbox2 когда выбираю значения из первого из базы данных подгружается информация и заносится во второй. Хочу сделать, что б фоновом потоке информация во втором обновлялась  т.к. данные могут быстро меняться. это всё написал и сделал кнопку обновить-всё работает.

теперь хочу без кнопки, чтоб вначале запускался поток и каждые `х` секунд/минут выполнял обновления...- и это работает. Но если я делаю обновления более частыми (для наглядности 1500 мс, что б выловить исключение) при нажатии на листбокс выдает исключение(как я заметилперед тем как обновится листбокс), но не всегда- на медленном обновлении его можно "не встретить", разве что нажать прям перед обновлением(как мне кажется, может и не прав).

Я пробовал в момент начала выполнения поток листбокс делать неактивным а при завершении цикла опять включать- не помогает. В исключении пишет Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. Я не пойму как не указывает, если листбокс есть со значениями. Подскажите почему это возникает, и что с этим делать, что б пользователь работал как обычно и при этом данные обновлялись?

---

Код длинный

разметка листбокса (всё как обычно, только телериковский)

```
<telerik:RadListBox Name="LB_Ocenki_Semester">
    <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate >
       <DataTemplate>
         <Grid >
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=nazvanieDisciplini, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="label24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />

            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ocenka, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Margin="160,-3,0,0" Height="23" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="label136" VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />       
       </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
       </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </telerik:RadListBox>

есть методы, например для получения таблицы дисциплин,оценок у студента на выбранном семестре

public DataTable Get_Semester_Students_Ocenki(string Zachetka,string Semester)
        {
            MyAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT  YearName,Zachetka,Disciplini.Disciplina,Ocenka as ocenka,Primechanie,NazvanieDisciplini as nazvanieDisciplini FROM UspevaemostOcenki INNER JOIN Disciplini on Disciplini.Disciplina=UspevaemostOcenki.Disciplina where zachetka={0} and YEARNAME={1}", Zachetka, Semester), MyConnection);
            Table_Semester_Students_Ocenki.Clear();
            try
            {
                MyAdapter.Fill(Table_Semester_Students_Ocenki);
            }
            catch { }
            return Table_Semester_Students_Ocenki;
        }

.... ..... и стоит привязка листбокса и DataView,который получается из запроса
LB_Ocenki_Semester.ItemsSource = new DataView(Con.Get_Semester_Students_Ocenki(Students_Semester_Zachetka_Selected.Text.ToString().Trim(), Selected_Semester_Nomer.Text.ToString().Trim()));

пока всё без проблем.

а позже добавляю кнопку "автоматически обновлять" и пишу обработчик

*thread = new Thread(this.Proc);
            thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();*

public void Proc()
        {
            while (true)
            {                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
                { Refresh_Selected_Student_Semester_Info(); });
                Thread.Sleep(1500);//для наглядности-ставлю часто
            }
        }

    (Con- это sqlconnection,)

        public void Refresh_Selected_Student_Semester_Info()
                {
                    Con.MyAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select UspevaemostOcenki.YearName,Disciplini.Disciplina,NazvanieDisciplini, Ocenka,Primechanie,Years.YearName as YN from UspevaemostOcenki inner join Disciplini on UspevaemostOcenki.Disciplina = Disciplini.Disciplina inner join Years on Years.Nomer = UspevaemostOcenki.YearName where zachetka={0} and UspevaemostOcenki.YearName={1}", Students_Semester_Zachetka_Selected.Text.ToString().Trim(), Selected_Semester_Nomer.Text.ToString().Trim()), Con.MyConnection);
                    Con.Table_Semester_Students_Ocenki.Clear();
                    try
                    {
                        Con.MyAdapter.Fill(Con.Table_Semester_Students_Ocenki);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

    Это всё работает, если на него "не дышать", как только начинаю много клацать-вылетает исключение
```

Comment: закрывай соединение 

    Con.MyAdapter.Close();

Comment: У меня Con- свойство типа sqlconnection ,я его 1 раз открываю и когда создаю новый запрос, то обращаюсь к нему, не создавая каждый раз новое соединение и не закрывая его (в видеоуроках Гудка смотрел) и до данного момента всё работало....хотя надо попробовать закрывать а потом открывать, просто вроде както не рационально и большая нагрузка...хотя может не прав...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, про ссылку на объект проверять нужно

```
var list = ListBox.Item;

if(list != null) {
 // погнали

}
```

ну или как там у тебя, а про соединение то его нужно закрывать, иначе при частом обращении будет исключение

```
void a(object sender, EventArgs e) {
conn.Open();
// code
conn.Close();
}
```

а про какие ты запросы шлешь на обновление я не понял, не проще ли добавить событие SelectedChanged (не помню точно, вроде такое)то обновлять второй комбобокс по идентификатору ListBox.Text

Comment: У меня при selectedchanged так и стоит и всё работает, но если пользователь выделил один элемент и не менял ничего скажем 10 мин,то он будет продолжать работать может с уже не существующими данными, а если этим же самым занимается поток, то может возникнуть исключение...может!..если я начну часто в это время клацать (для прикола,что б впоймать) по листбоксу2 то в какойто момент оно выскочет...я вообще не пойму- от куда оно берётся.

Comment: бросай код, поправлю

Comment: Он не понимает Item - var list = ListBox.Item; а что надо сделать, чтоб добавился Item?